# Dart HttpClientRequest.postUrl() does not work as intended

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am using Lucia in my Express server which is the backed for my Flutter app. I've followed the documentation and created a signout route in Express. The JavaScript code works as intended.

```
router.post("/signout", async (req, res) => {
  const authRequest = auth.handleRequest(req, res);
  const session = await authRequest.validate(); // or `authRequest.validateBearerToken()`
  console.log(req.headers);
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!session) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  await auth.invalidateSession(session.sessionId);

  authRequest.setSession(null);

  return res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    message: "User signed out successfully"
  });
});
```

When I call this endpoint from Dart it always returns 401 however when making the same request using fetch from JS, it correctly returns 200 and signs out the user.
NOTE: When I change this endpoint to be a GET endpoint instead, the dart get request works correctly as expected and the endpoint returns 200.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here's the Dart post request:

```
Future<HttpClientResponse> _postWithSession(String endpoint,
      {Map<String, String>? body}) async {
    var cookies = await _getCookies(endpoint);
    if (cookies.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception("Session cookie not found");
    }
    var req = await _client.postUrl(Uri.parse(endpoint));
    req.cookies.addAll(cookies);
    req.headers
        .set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    body != null ? req.write(jsonEncode(body)) : req.write(jsonEncode({}));
    var res = await req.close();
    await _updateCookies(endpoint, res.cookies);
    return res;
  }
```

Here's what a successful request should look like cURL:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/signout" -X POST -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" -H "Cookie: auth_session=<session_key>"
```

Comment: Since you are currently using HTTP can you capture the working and non-working requests in, say, wireshark - and compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can modify version of your _postWithSession function that adds the Origin header:

Future<HttpClientResponse> _postWithSession(String endpoint,
      {Map<String, String>? body}) async {
    var cookies = await _getCookies(endpoint);
    if (cookies.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception("Session cookie not found");
    }
    var req = await _client.postUrl(Uri.parse(endpoint));
    req.headers.addAll({
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      HttpHeaders.originHeader: "http://localhost:3000", // Replace with your app's origin
      HttpHeaders.cookieHeader: cookies.join("; "), // Join multiple cookies if needed
    });
    body != null ? req.write(jsonEncode(body)) : req.write(jsonEncode({}));
    var res = await req.close();
    await _updateCookies(endpoint, res.cookies);
    return res;
  }


please replace http://localhost:3000 with the correct origin of your Flutter app.
```